# Spectrum of the ring of formal power series over integers

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, formal-power-series

Let $\mathbb{Z}[[X]]$ be the formal power series ring over $\mathbb{Z}$.

I want to understand

- the set of prime ideals $\rm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}[[X]])$
- maximal ideals $\rm{Spm}(\mathbb{Z}[[X]])$ and
- the Jacobson radical $J(\mathbb{Z}[[X]])$.

How can one write these sets explicitly?

Comment: Not sure for the classification of characteristic $0$ prime ideals. For example $\Bbb{Z}[[X]]/(X-p)$ is isomorphic to the $p$-adic integers.

Answer (score 6):

Maximal ideals are of the form $(p,X)$ for a prime $p$ (see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Algebraic_properties_of_the_formal_power_series_ring)) and the Jacobson radical is the intersection of the maximal ideals, so it equals $(X)$. Alternatively there is a proof at [Jacobson radical of formal power series over an integral domain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2608398/jacobson-radical-of-formal-power-series-over-an-integral-domain).

[Edit: a previous version of this answer contained a wrong description of height 1 primes in the formal power series ring.]

In case of the polynomial ring $\text{Spec}\,\mathbb Z[X]$ all prime ideals may be described as being of the form $(p,f)$ for $p$ prime or zero and $f$ irreducible mod $p$ or zero (see [Spectrum of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221107/spectrum-of-mathbbzx)).

A similar characterization for $\mathbb Z[[X]]$ is that every nonzero prime ideal is either:

- a maximal ideal of height 2 of the form $(p,X)$, or
- a height 1 prime ideal of the form $(f)$ for $f\in\mathbb Z[[X]]$ irreducible

This follows since it is also a UFD, (hence height 1 primes are principal) and its Krull dimension is also 2 (hence height 2 primes are maximal).

It should be noted that a polynomial may change its irreducibility when considered as a formal power series. See https://www.jstor.org/stable/27642533 for examples and discussion of the irreducibility problem for integer power series. In terms of the map of schemes $$\text{Spec}\, \mathbb Z[[X]] \to \text{Spec}\,\mathbb Z[X]$$ this means that

- there is some ramification over irreducible polynomials which split as a power series
- besides power series, the generic fiber also includes some *polynomials*
  (which are reducible as a polynomial, but all but one of the factors has constant term $\pm1$, thus is a unit when considered as a power series).

Comment: The second to last sentence is wrong. For example, the fiber over $(X)$ to $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ has more things, for example the ideal $(X - p)$ for a prime $p$.

Comment: @JSquared Sorry, I can’t follow your comment. The second to last sentence in this answer is about DVRs, but your comment mentions a polynomial ring. $(X-p)$ is not a proper ideal in the formal power series ring, as $1/(X-p)$ is expressible by geometric series.

Comment: Let $f = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nX^n$ be some power series such that $(X-p)(f) = 1$. Then, by the multiplication law for formal power series, $a_0 * p = 1$, (colloquially, $a = 1/p$. But $p$ does not have an inverse in $\mathbb{Z}$.

If you want to write it as a geometric series, you'd have to write it as $1/(1-(1+p-x))$. Then if you expand the resulting geometric series and collect in terms of x, component will be an infinite series of with binomial coefficients, which won't converge in $\mathbb{Z}_p$--but if it converged to an integer it would have had to in $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: @JSquared I don’t see your point. The second to last sentence is about formal power series over a field, not a general ring. It then applies that fact only to $\mathbb F_p$ and $\mathbb Q$. It seems like you are considering the case when $k=\mathbb Z$, which is not a field, and the statement would no longer hold.

Comment: Perhaps I've not communicated my objection well. I'm objecting to the claim that "the prime ideals are all of the form $(X,p),(X),(p)$ or $(0)$ for a prime $p$", for example $(X-p)$ is a proper ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[[X]]$ which is not of this form, the proof is the first two sentences of my previous comment.

Comment: @JSquared Thanks I see what you mean now. The first bullet point in the answer is already wrong then.

Comment: @JSquared since the question is closed i thought it best to edit the answer than delete it. Please let me know if you find something wrong